# How to create a process in Apex page?

Tags: oracle-apex

[Apex 5.1]

I have an apex page and I'm trying to create a process.

The process should raise an error as follows

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekmFF.png)

When I submit the page, the process doesn't run.

Does anyone have an idea please ?

[Why do I want to raise an error in a process ? This question is out of topic. It's for testing purposes]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a branch to page 20 . this branch, it's conditional? are you redirect to page 20? i don't really know what you want to do but you have to put this branch after processing.